# Why does image rotation prevent overfitting in few-shot learning?

Tags: machine-learning, image-processing, feature-engineering

From [this paper](http://proceedings.mlr.press/v48/santoro16.pdf) in section 4.1:

> To reduce the risk of overfitting, we performed data augmentation by randomly
>   translating and rotating character images. We also created new classes
>   through 90◦, 180◦ and 270◦ rotations of existing data.

I looked through 2 papers after this one came out and they also say that they rotate images in this same manner (although not explicitly stated in those papers, if I understand correctly, they didn't bother translating images because they use convolutional networks that are translation-invariant)

How does rotating images prevent overfitting in a few-shot classifier, and why choose (90, 180, 270) degree rotations? Why would those specifically count as a "new class?"